# How to track quota usage per end-user for LUIS service?

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-application-insights, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

For a Microsoft Bot Framework app made using C#.NET I would like to track the usage of LUIS AI for each end user.

1. I would like to know if there is any in-built option available in Azure, LUIS service, Application Insights, Microsoft Bot Framework (C#.NET SDK), Azure Bot Service/App Service.
2. Also I was thinking about logging, could this be done manually using logging messages to a database only in the methods having `[LuisIntent]` attribute, will this suffice? (tracking user messages involving LUIS API calls only will be enough I think, one need not track every message from a user to the bot)

The following thread that I created [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4079) on GitHub for Microsoft BotBuilder Issues explains it in detail.

Could you please provide your suggestions.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier if you stored each message that a user sent to a central database that logged who sent the message. You could also have that same database store the information about which LUIS model your use was using when they sent the message. 

For example, you store the following in your database:
1) User information (client/user number)
2) The LUIS model they used, 
3) The App they used to access the LUIS model

Answer (score 0):

No there's no inbuilt option available in Azure/Luis to track per user usage of your bot. Secondly, yes, you can try logging each user interaction with your Luis service & keep an eye on quota usage but for that, you need to store user identity as well. Please check snap here, I have done the same. To answer how I did this, I simply added a logger class as following:

```
public static class Logger
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Log data into text file
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="text"></param>
        public static void Log(string text)
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\Log\\Loginfo.txt", text +Environment.NewLine);
        }
 }
```

[image]

In addition, if you wish to track basic details like api hits/key usage etc. you can move to dashboard tab of luis service & check it out.

[image]

Comment: "Please check snap here, I have done the same." can you add more details on how you made it for the OP please?

Comment: @NicolasR I have edited an answer, please check it out & let me know if it helps.